# How to resolve HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in curl php

Tags: php, curl

I have to hit one `.aspx` page url from php code i am trying to hiting using curl but i am getting bellow error and there is no white space in url.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2015 08:31:13 GMT Connection: close Content-Length: 311
```

Bellow is the code of curl which i am trying to hit.so any body will tell why iam getting this error.

```
$api_url = 'http://www.test/xyz/OnlineOrder.aspx?';
     $url= $api_url . 'InvoiceNo=' . $invoice;
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
     echo $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: How is the target service specified?

Comment: that is the company genrate's the bar code's for generated order

Comment: I'm thinking of the interface. How's that specified? HTTP method, parameters, headers, auth etc.

Comment: target service dont have any api i just have to hit there url with some parameters like i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Basically, your HTTP request seems to be fine anyway, since you receive a qualified answer. I guess the server assumes something different to be sent to it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the `Http response 200 ok` I have observed carefully the url and i found one parameter with white space that was cause the Bad request.Any way if you got some thing like problem remove the white space from url and there parameter.

using `urlencode($url);`

Comment: sometimes urlencode() doesn't produce the desired effect. In my case neither did rawurlencode(). I had to resort to str_replace to replace the spaces ONLY to get the server to return a 200. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995268/php-curl-bad-request-400-mapquest-geocoding

Answer (score 7):

If it help anyone, my issue is I have to use `POST` method in curl but no `POST` parameters has been require, as API grab value from URL query string only. So, passing empty array in `POSTFIELDS` fixed my problem. My guess is it depends on Apache/PHP setting on server, whether it allows `POST` request without post parameters or not.

Comment: Thanks, that sorted my problem. Worked fine on my local but would not work on live until I added the empty array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

Comment: This was the solution for me

Comment: It works for me so. Although I don't use Apache. Thank you!