# Why curl return 400 bad request when i try to get page content?

Tags: php, web-scraping

i am trying to get web page content with `curl` from some websites but they return 400 bad request ( `file_get_contents` return empty ) here's the function i am using :

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate [how to resolve 400 bad request in curl php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944441/how-to-resolve-http-1-1-400-bad-request-in-curl-php)

Comment: urlencode($url) didn't solve the problem

Comment: @Gameek, read this article https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/400-bad-request

Answer (score 0):

Put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` line at the top file where you are calling this function.

It will generate the cause of an error.